# Copying styling/formatting from one WordPress widget to another with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I've inserted a pre-header widget into [my Wordpress blog](http://pla.za.com/). I would like for it to have the same formatting as the footer widget.

However, I've run up against two problems:

1. The heading in the top widget is h3, while the one at the bottom is h4. I tried manually overriding the h3 styling with h4 styling

   ```
   .pre-header-widget .h3 {
     font-size: 1.125em;`
     line-height: 1.34;`
   }
   ```

to no result. How can I change the h3 heading in the top widget to be the same as the heading in the footer widget?

2. (Thanks to enigma, 2 is now fixed.) Either I don't know how to use pseudo-classes (possible), or pseudo-classes are not working in the pre-header widget, because I can't get the links in the pre-header widget to behave the same way they do in the footer.
3. This is everything I've got aimed at the pre-header widget now:

   ```
   .pre-header-widget {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 2.5em;
     margin-bottom: 0.5em;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: center;
   }

   .pre-header-widget ul {
     list-style-image: none;
     list-style-position: outside;
     list-style-type: none;
     font-size: .813em;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.85;
     letter-spacing: .08em;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .pre-header-widget a, .pre-header-widget a:link, .pre-header-widget a:visited {
     color: #8c8c8c;
   }

   .pre-header-widget a:active, .pre-header-widget a:focus, .pre-header-widget a:hover {
     color: #white;
     font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
     opacity: 0.6;
     transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
     transition-delay: 0s;
     transition-property: all;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
   }
   ```

Comment: nice domain name btw

Comment: Didn't see this. Thanks! I am really chuffed with it. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following css should do what you want. I'd recommend using FireBug or some other in browser developer tools for this kind of work.

```
.pre-header-widget h3 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    line-height: 1.34;
}


.pre-header-widget a, .pre-header-widget a:link, .pre-header-widget a:visited {
    color: #8c8c8c;
}

.pre-header-widget a:active, .pre-header-widget a:focus, .pre-header-widget a:hover {
    color: #ededed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The code for the widget's heading doesn't appear to work.

I do use the developer tools, but I'm still unfamiliar with how it's all put together, hence my fumbling.

Comment: I tried removing the other custom CSS aimed at pre-header-widget, and the heading still didn't look any different.

Comment: It works fine when I try it in firebug, but I can't test your implementation of it. If you put the css I've suggested up on the site, then I might be able to tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: The code is already in the Custom CSS box. I've cleared my cache, and the heading still doesn't look like it looks in the footer in Chrome or Firefox.

I've added the rest of the pre-header-widget code in my OP, if you need it.

Comment: @dimi The issue is that something is parsing the text you enter to make it html 'friendly', and the first line is becoming `.pre-header-widget &gt; h3 {`. The easiest way to resolve this is just to remove the `>` - I have edited my answer. Hope that solves it :)

Comment: Thank you, it's working!

So h is not a class, or at least isn't treated as one. Got it.

I've never seen `>` used in CSS. I'll have to find out what that was about.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Dimi `h4` is not a class at all, no, it's a tag in it's own right, just like `div` or `span`. `>` implies that the following element must be a direct child of the preceeding, but in this case that's kinda irrelevant. Glad it helped, accepting and or upvoting is appreciated if this has answered your question. Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Sadly, I'm new, so my upvotes don't matter. You do deserve it, and I'm sorry I don't have more tangible appreciation to offer in return. :)

Comment: @Dimi no worries at all, I don't really do this for the points anyway. You should be able to accept the answer by clicking the little tick next to the upvote / downvote buttons. This marks the question as resolved for other people.